Showing the supremum squares to 2
In class, my real analysis teacher defined $\sqrt 2 = \sup \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x^2 < 2\}$ and left proving that this definition implies $\sqrt 2 ^2 = 2$ as an exercise. But I haven't been able to prove this without referencing the existence of a square root of $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, which he said we couldn't do. How can I solve this exercise?

IVT implies the existence of a square root of 2.

You can do it by explicitly exhibiting a sequence of numbers $x$ such that $x^2 < 2$ but which get arbitrarily close to $2$. There's a cheeky way to do this by iterating a fractional linear transformation; this is somewhere near the beginning of baby Rudin, IIRC.

Use of the IVT provides an elegant proof.  However, the assertion can be proven without the IVT, by relying only on the Least Upper Bound axiom.  See this answer.

Consider the continuous function $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, given by $f(t) = t^n$ and $\alpha$ be a positive real number. By Archimedean property of $\Bbb R$, there exists a $N \in \Bbb N$ such as $N > \alpha$. We have $0 = f(0) < \alpha$ and $f(N) = N^n \geq N > \alpha$. So applying IVP, there exists $x \in [0,N]$ such that $x^n = \alpha$.
In your case $n = 2, \alpha =2$.
